# How to Limit Access in an Amazon S3 Bucket to a Specific Folder Containing Course Information Through WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, woocommerce

Rookie S3 user here looking to troubleshoot a problem I encountered while helping some friends with their business. Their business revolves around selling courses and the program they use is WooCommerce and they attach course files through WordPress. The way these courses work is that there is a live video call where people like to join in so the product on WooCommerce initially holds the details for the upcoming call and afterward additional audio and transcripts are added to the product for sale. The problem is that this means people who had bought the course prior to this call would not receive these files unless permission to see them was manually given. As this is redundant and troublesome, my thought was to change the purchase to instead give a link which goes into an Amazon S3 bucket labeled courses and give them access to a specific folder within it. Ideally, this link would let them see new files lives and furthermore would limit the size of data on the website which is hosted on a dedicated server (save some $$$ on hosting fees, 2 birds 1 stone) The problem however is that since I am a complete novice to this style of coding, I am unsure of how to do this although I do think it is possible given an answer is already out there or if I can bull and jam my way through a section of code. The reason I am looking to sort out courses as folders inside a bucket instead of individual buckets is that the number of courses the website currently has is nearing 200 and if an effort was made to change those then it would be well over the 100 bucket limit in addition to being an exercise in repetition. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This question could be improved.  I am not entirely sure I understand what exactly you want to do.  could you read through it and remove any extraneous detail?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to host content on S3, but want to achieve some degree of access control on that content.

The most straightforward way to do this, the one that involves minimal S3 integration, is to *presign* an S3 url for the user.  the presigned url would be good for a limited time and could be generated directly before redirecting the user to that URL by your wordpress site, which would in turn hold aws access credentials.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/zh_cn/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service/s3-presigned-url.html eplains more about this from a php perspective, which I'm guessing is the right lens for you.

This allows some modicum of access control ( the users can still share the document after they've accessed it, but at least it's not just public).

If you don't need access control, you can make the s3 object public and omit the signing altogether.